# How to validate the range of a query parameter on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

There's a payload that I need to paginate and now it works but I want to validate the range of limit query parameter. I tried adding the `@Range` annotation but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me to validate this?

```
    @GetMapping("/ambassadors")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Page<Ambassador> getAmbassadors(@Range(min = 10, max = 20) @RequestParam int limit,
            @Range(min = 0) @RequestParam int pageNumber) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit);
        return ambassadorRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `@Validated` annotation to your controller.

ex:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {

}
```